# C# Selenium Checkbox without ID,Name or something else

Tags: selenium-webdriver, checkbox, selenium-chromedriver

I need to check a checkbox but i dont know how to use XPath and any try failed, theres no other option because the Checkbox have no id or name or something else.

```
<div data-radium="true" style="cursor: pointer; color: rgb(20, 23, 26); display: flex; flex-direction: column;">

<svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="far" data-icon="square" class="svg-inline--fa fa-square fa-w-14 " role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512">

<path fill="currentColor" d="M400 32H48C21.5 32 0 53.5 0 80v352c0 26.5 21.5 48 48 48h352c26.5 0 48-21.5 48-48V80c0-26.5-21.5-48-48-48zm-6 400H54c-3.3 0-6-2.7-6-6V86c0-3.3 2.7-6 6-6h340c3.3 0 6 2.7 6 6v340c0 3.3-2.7 6-6 6z"></path></svg></div>
```

I want to check the checkbox but dont know how to get it and i dont know how to use XPath, all XPath typess i tried dont work. the checkbox is implemented with java i think.